# Remove Duplicate Arrays in PHP for laravel framework

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have more than 4 arrays in single variable as shown below

```
$myArray = Array ( [0] => NA [1] => NA [2] => USA [3] => NA [4] => Texas )Array ( [0] => NA [1] => NA [2] => UK [3] => NA [4] => Texas  )Array ( [0] => NA [1] => NA [2] => USA [3] => NA [4] => Texas ) Array ( [0] => NA [1] => NA [2] => UAE [3] => NA [4] => Texas )
```

Now i need to compare each and every array of [2] index.

If second index ([2] => USA) is present in some other array then delete duplicate array.

Finally the arrays should look like this

```
Array ( [0] => NA [1] => NA [2] => USA [3] => NA [4] => Texas )Array ( [0] => NA [1] => NA [2] => UK [3] => NA [4] => Texas )Array ( [0] => NA [1] => NA [2] => UAE [3] => NA [4] => Texas ).
```

I have tried this but not able to sort it out.

```
$myArray = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $myArray)));
```

Is there any way?

Comment: i have edited my question. Array looks like as edited, it does not contain any comma's to separate arrays

Comment: @DPS In php array elements are separated by commas, but when you use `print_r` to output an array, it only shows a dummy readable version of an array, which is not a valid syntax for PHP. In php, so you need to use `var_export` to output an executable array. Here is a demo with [print_r](https://eval.in/899047) and [var_export](https://eval.in/899046) see for your self. It is the same array but `print_r` removes the commas and quotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `foreach` loop for this, like [DEMO](https://eval.in/898735):

```
$match = [];
foreach($myArray as $key => $value)
{
    if(!in_array($value[2], $match))
    {
        $match[] = $value[2];
        continue;
    }
    unset($myArray[$key]);
}
```

This will remove all of the arrays which have duplicate value for `[2]`

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate through your array with two loops and check the second index value in each of the inner arrays and if there is a duplicated value you can just unset the second one.

Here is a piece of code that should do well:

```
<?php

for($i=0; $i < count($myArray); $i++) {
    for($j=$i+1; $j < count($myArray); $j++) {
        if ($myArray[$i][2] == $myArray[$j][2]) {
            unset($myArray[$j][2]);
        }
    }
}
```

P.S: The code is not tested and may need some modifications, but you could get the main idea.